# How to manually install files in c:\windows\assembly?

Tags: .net

I had been facing the problem which i could say faced by quite a number of people out there.

I'm interested with one of the answers given for this problem; quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/561530/3195477:

> So it turns out that the .NET files were copied to c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies, however, they were
> never registered in the GAC.
>
> I ended up manually dragging the files in c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies to c:\windows\assembly
> and the application worked on that problem machine. you could also do
> this programmatically with gacutil.
>
> So it seems that something happened to .NET during the install, but
> this seems to correct the problem.

i tried to drag and even copy & paste the files in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\` to `c:\windows\assembly` but I couldn't maybe the system din allow that. How would I possibly transfer the files then?

Answer (score -1):

What for ? Just place this dll in the directory where you application is.