# error when installing windows application on other pc

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005

I had windows application and I published it and I installed it in other pc and when I was installing in this error apeared(you cannot run application that require that assembly microsoft sql server.connection info 9.0.242.0  ......)

Comment: I bet that's not *actually* what the error message said. Please don't paraphrase, it's hard enough to debug this type of problem remotely as it is. If my psychic abilities are properly tuned, I suspect that the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-version) will provide some hints on solving the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Did it say _exactly_ that? Please paste the whole error message. Where did the message come from, from the installer?

Comment: @BlackBear: Why, exactly, do you hate C#? Because you can use it to produce applications that display error messages? Is there a language where that is *not* possible?

Comment: @Cody Gray: because it's based on the .NET, so you must have the .NET installed in order to execute C# apps. BTW I hate Java too. They "pollutes" your pc with dlls reg keys etc

Comment: @BlackBear: C++ applications generally require a runtime library, at least in Windows. Additionally, this error has absolutely *nothing* to do with the .NET Framework. The only part we can see indicates it's about SQL Server, which even a C or C++ application could have a dependency on.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Okok, I'm wrong. but I don't like it anyway :)

Comment: @BlackBear: Good to know. Consider adding that to your profile's "About Me" section, rather than as a comment to questions about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random guess...

You need with either [SQL Server native client or SQL Server SMO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=df0ba5aa-b4bd-4705-aa0a-b477ba72a9cb&displaylang=en). or both

Answer (score 0):

You say "published" so I'm guessing it's a ClickOnce deployment.

One gotcha of the automated ClickOnce deployment (at least, it was as of VS2008) is that it doesn't automatically pick up the dependencies of any projects you reference in the project you publish from - you have to add the references into your main project by hand, then they will be added to the manifest, and then deployed to client machines upon installation.

Hope this helps.