# windows application setup error

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error when installing windows application on other pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209626/error-when-installing-windows-application-on-other-pc)

I had windows application and I published it and I installed it in other pc and when I was installing in this error apeared(unable to install or run the application.the application requires that assembly microsoft.sqlserver.connectioninfo version9.0.242 be installed in the global assembly cache (GAC) first.)

Comment: **[I've seen this question once before already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209626/error-when-installing-windows-application-on-other-pc)**. You weren't willing to provide any additional information when asked before, and this question isn't any better than that one.

Comment: I can't understand why this is a question... isn't the error message entirely clear?  I would guess that you haven't installed the assembly microsoft.sqlserver.connectioninfo version 9.0.242 in the global assembly cache have you?  I think you probably need to do that first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Project Properties page.
- Go to `Publish` tab.
- Click on `Application Files` button.
- Change the Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll from "Prerequisite" to "Include".
- Republish and try installing on the other computer again.

Comment: microsoft.sqlserver.connectioninfo dosenot find in publish tab

Comment: @KareemSaad It should be ` Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll`.

Comment: I doesnot find Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post where they discuss this issue and it's solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/228a534e-a978-469c-9964-40d207ef8669