# Error Message: System Update Required

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, clickonce, stdole

I have an **application in VS2008[windows form application].**

And I make publish it using Publishing feature in VS2008.

[Project=>Project Properties=>Publish=>Publish Now].

When I install the publish project in my own PC its working well….but at some clients PC it gives me following error message.
and don't let me install an application at that PC...
installation process stops Immediately.

[image]

**What is going wrong with my published application?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install or run the application. The application requires stdole Version 7.0.3300.0 in the GAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-version)

Comment: You need to include `stdole.dll` as a required dependency for your application in the Publish tab. Darin's answer to the duplicate question has complete step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-version

Comment: @Pritesh - make use of gacutil.exe to register you external dll

Comment: **NO**. Do not use gacutil.exe to register your DLL. You should *never* register DLLs in the GAC manually. This is *completely* wrong. The answers to the linked question have the correct solution, and it's much easier to implement. @Pranay: Please stop telling people to do this. There is a *much* better solution to this problem.

Comment: @Cody Gray, ok thank you so much for direct to right direction.....

Comment: @Cody Gray - ok.........you are hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is .net framework is installed on client machine ?
2. is all dll are registered by you in GAC which is utilize by you in your project ? register you dll using : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx by using GACUTIL

Comment: for first one I say yes...... for second one i say no..or i mean i don't know how to do it.... how to register .dll in GAC? Thanks.......

Comment: You should *never* register DLLs in the GAC yourself. Leave that to an installer or other automated deployment mechanism (such as ClickOnce).