# How do I include all required assemblies when publishing C# console app that relies on EWS with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, exchangewebservices

I created a simple C# console app that relies on an Exchange login through the EWS Managed API. When I publish using Visual Studio publishing wizard (Build > Publish) I was able to deploy to a shared drive. However, when others who don't have the EWS Managed API installed on their computer try to run the app they get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEQ7N.png

The assembly does not show up as an option under the project publish settings (Right click on project > Properties > Publish > Prerequisites).

How do I make sure the EWS assembly is included when I publish the console app?

Comment: for that particular .dll set the `CopyLocal` property = true.. this way it will be in the bin directory.. or you could create a folder like 3rPartyAssemblies, place the .dll's there.. and then remove the current reference, then re-add them back pointing to the shared assembly folder..

Comment: Or alternatively you could do what the error message proposes: put it in the GAC of the target machine.

Comment: Changing the `CopyLocal` property or making a copy of the dll didn't work for me for the purposes of publishing to a shared network location. Following the top voted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-versio) seemed to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this question:
([Error message "Unable to install or run the application. The application requires stdole Version 7.0.3300.0 in the GAC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-versio))

"Try going to the Publish tab in the project properties and then select the Application Files button. Then set the following properties:

- Publish status to Include"