# Unable to install stdole.dll using ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have published a C# program and sold it to others. A couple of people are having the same problem as on [Error message "Unable to install or run the application. The application requires stdole Version 7.0.3300.0 in the GAC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558361/unable-to-install-or-run-the-application-the-application-requires-stdole-versio) , but I'm running into problems with the proposed solutions.

FYI, my C# program is based on .NET 3.5.

Dragging `stdole.dll` to `C:\windows\assembly` didn't work on one of my customer's machines. The files within `C:\windows\assembly` do not "look like" files in other folders. The columns in that folder are Assembly Name, Version, Culture, Public Key Token, and Processor Architecture (rather than Name, Date Modified, Type, and Size.

I searched for the `gacutil.exe` on my Windows 8.1 machine and found 9 of them, so I'm not sure which one to run. Or which one to run on my customers machines, which can be any version of Windows.

I tried RPF's answer, but when I went to the 'Application Files' screen, `stdole.dll` wasn't on my list. That solution would have been nice because it would fix the problem for all of my customers.

Then I saw Magnus' comment that Click-Once can't install to the GAC. Kiquenet asked the follow-up, but never got a reply, so I'll ask it here...

How do I solve this problem so that I don't have to run the GACUTIL for every (or most of) my new customers?

Comment: It is a PIA, you can't deploy PIAs with ClickOnce.  PIAs have been obsolete for the past 5 years, time to move ahead.  Target at least .NET 4.0, set the assembly reference's Embed Interop Type to True so you don't have to deploy it.

Comment: Will that affect which versions of Windows my program will run on? (Thanks!)

Comment: My concern is that many of my customers have older machines and I doubt they'll upgrade just because of my program. I'm especially worried that people who have already purchased will get shut out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate solution that did one thing-it installed stdole.dll in the GAC and that worked for the people who had the problem. It might not solve it for everyone, I can't be sure...

Answer (score 0):

Include it in application files from properties. By default it is in prerequisite auto mode.

[image: See this image]